# Candlestick shift in combo chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart API, primarily Combo Chart to display different data in the same graph area. When I use CandleStick alone it looks fine:
[image: candlestick only]

However when I add another bar series it causes slight shift and now candles look all messed up.
[image: candlestick with bar]

It seems that width of left Vertical axis causes this slight shift. Problem is, I need both axis shown.
I tried adjusting `strokewidth` of both falling and rising, it just make it look fuzzy. So making `strokewidth` to less than 1 is not too effective.

**Code**

```
var options = {
    title: jsondata['chart_title'],
    hAxis: {direction: -1},
    vAxes: {0:{format:y_units},1:{format:"$#.##"}},
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {0: {type: "candlesticks", targetAxisIndex: 1}},
    candlestick: {
        fallingColor:{
            strokeWidth: .5
        },
        risingColor:{
            strokeWidth: .5
        }
    },
    displayAnnotations: true,

    crosshair: { trigger: 'both' }
}
```

and actual drawing element

```
var chart = new google.visualization[jsondata['chart_type']](document.getElementById('chart_div'));
$.extend(options, {legend:{position:'bottom'}})
chart.draw(data, options);
```

**Sample Data**

```
['Mon', 11, 10, 8, 17, 1],
['Tue', 12, 17, 7, 28, 5],
['Wed', 6, 22, 5, 25, 0],
['Thu', 10, 11, 16, 11, 0],
['Fri', 15, 44, 25, 44, 3]
```

- Note: Data needs to be way LARGER for this to have effect, so copying paste this data 10 times should do the trick. When there are only few data points, candlesticks are fairly larger and even if there is an effect, it is marginal

Any suggestions to make it look normal?

Comment: Can you add code that replicates the problem to your question?

Comment: Can you add sample data as well?  I need to be able to replicate the problem entirely in order to figure out what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: Updated both! Data is just rough sample, it is really only a problem on LARGER data sets, so if you replicate that sample *10 lets say, then it will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect happens when you have too many bar-type (candlestick and bar) data points in a chart for the width of the chart.  When using a discrete (string-type) axis, each row of data is allocated (width / rows) pixels for the bar group, and bars are aligned side-by-side within the group, which generates some odd effects when the group width gets narrow.  You can address this problem by using some combination of the following:

1. increase the width of the chart
2. increase the width of the bar groups (via the `bar.groupWidth` option, set to `'100%'` to maximize)
3. set the `isStacked` option to `true`
4. use a [Control](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) to filter your data and make the displayed data set smaller

Comment: Good explanation! I did #2, rest are not really an option for me. Do you know if there is a way to widen the actual candle and not the width of the border? I looked through documentation, didnt spot any. Also any way to change width of the stick, and not the candle? Thickness comparison between stick and candle is bit off i think

Comment: No, those are not configurable, sorry.

Comment: Overlaying one top of the other (bar and candles) would be great or widening the candles. I guess I must succumb to this, thanks for explanation!